# iPhone 5 and updates from my Hotmail.com account

Tags: data-synchronization, contacts, iphone

Just got my new iPhone issued to me at work.  When I put in my Hotmail.com address it automatically attached all those contacts to my phone.  Since that time I have gone into the Hotmail.com contacts and cleaned it all up by deleting many unused and old contacts.
How do I get the phone to now update the new contact list??

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind,  I found my answer at How to Geek  howtogeek.com

Comment: If you want to explain what fixed it, you might help lots of people. If not, let me know and I can clean this all up. Cheers and thanks for answering that you're solved it!